# How can I change font zoom progression in mintty

Tags: fonts, cygwin, mintty

ctrl+/- change font size on mintty terminal.

However, the steps in some place are quite large. Can I change the progression so I can fit to my window better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: there’s no way to configure this behaviour without modifying the source.

### Under the hood

Since mintty is free software (GPL), I checked out its source code from the [mintty GitHub repository](https://github.com/mintty/mintty). It’s written in C and the code turns out to be fairly readable (I’m a sysadmin, not a programmer) and I’ve copied some of the relevant code here.

You can see from the following code in `wininput.c` that the zooming happens in discrete steps of 1 (increase the font size) or -1 (decrease) that are added to the current font size and that no configuration settings are used to control the size of the steps.

```
// Font zooming
if (cfg.zoom_shortcuts && mods == MDK_CTRL) {
  int zoom;
  switch (key) {
    when VK_OEM_PLUS or VK_ADD:       zoom = 1;
    when VK_OEM_MINUS or VK_SUBTRACT: zoom = -1;
    when '0' or VK_NUMPAD0:           zoom = 0;
    otherwise: goto not_zoom;
  }
  win_zoom_font(zoom);
  return 1;
  not_zoom:;
}
```

The relevant functions are defined in `wintext.c`:

```
void
win_set_font_size(int size)
{
  size = size ? sgn(font_size) * min(size, 72) : cfg.font.size;
  if (size != font_size) {
    win_init_fonts(size);
    win_adapt_term_size();
  }
}

void
win_zoom_font(int zoom)
{
  win_set_font_size(zoom ? max(1, abs(font_size) + zoom) : 0);
}
```

The `win_adapt_term_size` function ensures that the window size adapts to display the rows and lines in units of the new font size.

Note that `sgn` is a macro which returns the sign of a number (represented as an integer). From `std.h`:

```
#define sgn(x) ({ typeof(x) x_ = (x); (x_ > 0) - (x_ < 0); })
```

From `config.c`, we can see that the initial font size is taken from the `FontHeight` configured in `~/.minttyrc`.

```
{"FontHeight", OPT_INT, offcfg(font.size)},
```

### Font size appearance

How the differences in font size are displayed depends on the both the selected font and the font rendering software.

I’ve attached a screenshot showing how Lucida Console and Consolas are displayed at different font sizes in Windows 7 using DirectWrite, the newer font rendering API released with Windows 7 to replace the older GDI rendering engine.

[image: Fonts displayed at different font sizes]

As you can see, the variation in the rendered size of the font is not exactly linearly in proportion to the specified font size. I remember spending time choosing a font that displayed well at different sizes and Consolas (with ClearType enabled) gave me the best results.

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed answer. However, I do not think it is going up by 1. Or, if it is, something else is changing too. On a single press of ctl+ my "line" which filled 3/4 of term width is suddenly wrapping around it... Do you know a command line way to query current font size etc?

Comment: @ManInMoon I don’t know of any way to query the current font size for the terminal.
I’ve updated my answer with my understanding of how programs display fonts.
If you change your mintty font to Lucida Console or Consolas and your results are wildly different from the screenshot I posted, it would be useful to edit your answer to include a screenshot at the different sizes (set using mintty’s Options dialogue).